# Why would originate call fail when using the Asterisk API with the Context set to "default"?

Tags: asterisk

When I originate a call to an outside line, setting the context to "default" causes a voice to say "good bye" and then the call is immediately terminated.

If I call an extension, it works perfectly with or without the context property.

If I remove the context property entirely, then I can call both inside and outside lines.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need setup context default corectly.

Or use other context to do dialplan.

see this  links

[extensions.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf)

[dialout](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out)